# Help with possible Haskell type inference quiz questions

Tags: haskell, type-inference, inferred-type

```
foldr:: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mys :: a -> a
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
```

what is inferred type of:
a.map mys ::
b.mys map ::
c.foldr map ::
d.foldr map.mys ::

I've tried to create mys myself using mys n = n + 2 but the type of that is

```
mys :: Num a => a -> a
```

What's the difference between 'Num a => a -> a' and just 'a -> a'? Or what does 'Num a =>' mean? Is it that mys would only take Num type?

So anyways,
a) I got [a] -> [a] I think because it would just take a list and return it +2'd according to my definition of mys
b) (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] I think because map still needs take both arguments like (*3) and a list then returns [a] which goes to mys and returns [b]
c) I'm not sure how to do this 1.
d) I'm not sure how to do this 1 either but map.mys means do mys first then map right?

Are my answers and thoughts correct? If not, why not?

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Update: Apparently my original answer wasn't very helpful for the OP... See below the second HR for an appendix.)*

---

In situations like this, what you really want to do is to launch `ghci` and use `:t` to find out the type of various expressions. E.g.

```
:t foldr map
-- answer: foldr map :: [b] -> [b -> b] -> [b]
```

If you need to define a name first, use `let` (which would not be needed in a Haskell source file):

```
let mys = undefined :: a -> a
:t map mys
-- answer: [a] -> [a]
```

Note the use of `undefined` with an explicit type signature. It's perfectly ok for finding out the type of expressions of various forms and might even be useful in actual code as a placeholder at early planning stages.

The `Num a =>` is a type class constraint on `a`; see e.g. [Type Classes and Overloading](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html)  from "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell, Version 98" or [Chapter 6. Using Typeclasses](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html) from "Real World Haskell" for more information. (Basically, it does what you think it does. :-))

---

The above should be useful for verifying your answers (and the resources on type classes are good). As for how to solve problems of this kind yourself:

Type inference is an application of what is called "the unification algorithm". Google for "unification" for a number of resources; if you add a name of a programming language to your query, you'll likely find example implementations.

As for how to approach the examples at hand...

a. `map mys`: `map` takes a function of type `a -> b` and returns a function of type `[a] -> [b]`. In general, `a` can be different to `b`, but `mys` is of type `a -> a`, so the returned function will be of type `[a] -> [a]`.

Here's some hand-unification:

```
(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`  
(a -> a)`
      ^-- at this point we unify a with b;
          when propagated to the return type,
          this produces [a] -> [a]
```

b. `mys map`: `mys` is a function which takes an object of some type and returns an object of the same type. In particular, if you pass it an argument of type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, that will be the type of the return value.

Incidentally, there is only one "interesting" (not `undefined`) function whose type signature is `a -> a` (without type class constraints), namely `id`. See Philip Wadler's paper "Theorems for free!" (which you can download from [this page](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html)) for an extended discussion.

c. `foldr map`: Firstly, note that the `a`s and `b`s in `foldr`'s signature having nothing to do with those in `map`'s signature. It might be convenient to rename `map`'s `a` to `c` and `b` to `d` and use the signature `map :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]` to make this more readily apparent below. Also note that `(a -> b -> b)` is just a simpler way of writing `(a -> (b -> b))`.

More hand-unification (explanation follows below):

```
(a       -> (b  -> b))
(c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]
```

What happens here is that `foldr` takes a function argument of type `(a -> (b -> b))`. If you pass in `map` as that argument, the `a` gets unified with `c -> d`, the `b` with `[c]` and then again with `[d]`, which means `c` equals `d`.

The return value of `foldr` has type `b -> [a] -> b`; substituting the more specific types obtained in the previous paragraph we get

```
[c] -> [c -> c] -> [c]
             ^-- c equals d, right?
```

The `c` comes from our changed signature for `map`; with the original `b`, this becomes

```
[b] -> [b -> b] -> [b]
```

d. `foldr map . mys`: This is actually `(foldr map) . mys`, not `foldr (map . mys)` -- function application ("the invisible operator") binds the strongest! Combining a. and c. from above to solve this one is left as an exercise to the reader. ;-)

Comment: thanks, but I writing :t on my exam paper wont get me an answer. hehe.

thats why I'm trying to learn why is it [b] -> [b->b] -> [b]

Comment: Oh, I see. Hopefully my newly edited answer will be more helpful.

Comment: I got [a]->[a->a]->[a] for 'd'. :t check was correct, THANKS!